# go get fails with unrecognized import path after upgrading to go 1.10

Tags: go

**Before setting proxy:**

`$ go get -u google.golang.org/grpc`

```
package google.golang.org/grpc: unrecognized import path "google.golang.org/grpc" (https fetch: Get https://google.golang.org/grpc?go-get=1: dial TCP 172.217.160.145:443: connected: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.)
```

**After setting proxy:**

`$ go get -u google.golang.org/grpc`

```
package google.golang.org/grpc: unrecognized import path "google.golang.org/grpc" (https fetch: Get https://google.golang.org/grpc?go-get=1: proxyconnect tcp: EOF)
```

I have tried every solution I could find on StackOverflow. I am still not able to solve this issue.

`$ go env`

```
$ go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\gayr\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\gayr\GolandProjects
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\gayr\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build135172366=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: did you set HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY both to an http (not https) URL?

Comment: I set http_proxy for an http url, and https_proxy for an https url

Comment: I reset the https_proxy to have an http url, and it worked! Can't believe that was the issue! Thanks @VonC!

Comment: Fantastic, thanks @VonC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always set your HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY to an *http* URL

The proxy itself should be accessed through http, even if your URL query is https

Comment: does that mean the connection with the proxy server should always be `http`? Can't we have https connections with the proxy server by anymeans?

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya It is possible but not seen often: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/242946. And it is secure "enough": https://security.stackexchange.com/q/80715. See also https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23584